# android studio duplicate libraries

Tags: android, jar

> What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE
>       File1: /Users/KrikorHerlopian/AndroidStudioProjects/Heinz/app/libs/httpcore-4.3.2.jar
>       File2: /Users/KrikorHerlopian/AndroidStudioProjects/Heinz/app/libs/httpclient-4.3.3.jar
>       File3: /Users/KrikorHerlopian/AndroidStudioProjects/Heinz/app/libs/httpclient-cache-4.3.3.jar
>       File4: /Users/KrikorHerlopian/AndroidStudioProjects/Heinz/app/libs/fluent-hc-4.3.3.jar
>       File5: /Users/KrikorHerlopian/AndroidStudioProjects/Heinz/app/libs/httpmime-4.3.3.jar

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

I am getting this error when i run my app. i have copies library files to my libs folder. and i have this in my gradle  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

Answer (score 1):

Try excluding your duplicating license file in your build.gradle file

```
packagingOptions { 
exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to your `gradle.build`:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it will help you just add inside android{

}

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
}
```